# Maven - Integration-testing a multi-module rest api JavaEE project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, integration-testing, maven-3

My web-app project is made up of multiple modules and has structure like this:

```
project  //pom
|
|-- mod-pojo  //jar
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |-- test
|   `-- pom.xml
|
|-- mod-util  //jar
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |-- test
|   `-- pom.xml
|
|-- mod-wepapi-war //war
|   |-- pom.xml
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |   `-- com
|       |   |       `-- mycompany
|       |   |           `-- myapp
|       |   |               |-- HomeServlet.java
|       |   |               
|       |   |-- resources
|       |   |   |-- com
|       |   |   |   `-- mycompany
|       |   |   |       `-- myapp
|       |   |   |           `-- something.xml
|       |   |   `-- log4j.properties
|       |   `-- webapp
|       |       `-- WEB-INF
|       |           `-- web.xml
|       `-- test
|           `-- java
|               `-- com
|                   `-- mycompany
|                       `-- myapp
|                           |-- TestHome.java
`-- pom.xml
```

The build order is mod-pojo, mod-util and then mod-wepapi-war
Each module has it's own unit tests. I want to do integration testing of the whole app. I want the app to be deployed to a tomcat server before the integration tests run, which will basically perform tests by calling the APIs.

I did some research online but nothing really turned out helpful.

I don't want the integration tests to be run during mvn test and i dont want the unit tests to run when I run integration test.

I also want to get the coverage of IT (excluding UT).

What is the best way to write and run these integration tests?

P.S I am new to Java and Maven

Answer (score 0):

you can create another module for your integration tests and create a maven profile that will disable tests